# Закінчення "-ю" дієслів теперішнього часу першої особи одинини

Tags: дієвідмінювання

Нещодавно зауважив, що двоє моїх друзів з Черкащини при використанні деяких дієслів у першій особі однини не чергують приголосні, що стоять наприкінці кореня, а також пом'якшують їх, наприклад:

> - ходити - хо**дю** (замість "хо**джу**");
> - просити - про**сю** (замість "про**шу**");
> - косити - ко**сю** (замість "ко**шу**").

Наскільки поширене це явище? Чи є природними такі закінчення для української мови?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> У переважній більшості південно-східних діалектів за аналогією до інших
>   особових форм, зокрема до форми 3-ої особи множини, відбулося вирівнювання форм 1-ої особи однини, що виявилося в утраті чергування [**д**], [**т**], [**з**], [**с**] з шиплячими: хо**д'у**, во**д'у**, си**д'у**, бу**д'у**, кру**т'у**, ле**т'у**, во**з'у**, но**с'у** та ін.). Ареал цих говорів приблизно окреслюється такою лінією зі сходу на захід: північніше Харкова, Полтави, **Черкас**, Вінниці, Кам'янця-Подільського, Чернівців і далі на південний захід приблизно по р. Черемош.

Джерело: С. Бевзенко "Українська діалектологія" (Київ, 1980)

> Чи є природними такі закінчення для української мови?

Для південно-східного наріччя - так (зокрема, африкат [**дж**] взагалі має дуже обмежену сферу використання, треба було його чимось замінити), для літературної мови - ні, ні і ще раз ні. Доказ із [чинного правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm):

> У дієсловах другої дієвідміни в першій особі однини приголосні **д**, **т**,
>   **з**, **с** змінюються на **дж**, **ч**, **ж**, **ш**: води́ти —
>   *воджу́*, верті́ти — *верчу́*, вози́ти — *вожу́*, носи́ти — *ношу́.*

Answer (score 4):

Згідно з правилами, дієслова I дієвідміни [можуть](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE#.D0.94.D1.96.D1.94.D0.B2.D1.96.D0.B4.D0.BC.D1.96.D0.BD.D1.8E.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F_.D0.B4.D1.96.D1.94.D1.81.D0.BB.D1.96.D0.B2) мати закінчення на *-ю*:

> дієслова з односкладовою інфінітивною основою на **-и-, -у-**, які
>   зберігаються при дієвідмінюванні, а також похідні від них (жити, мити,
>   чути); в особових формах дієслів бити, вити (док. звити), лити, пити
>   кореневий голосний и не зберігається: б’ю — б’ють, в’ю — в’ють, ллю —
>   ллють, п’ю — п’ють;

...а також дієслова II дієвідміни першої особи (сплю, стою). Наведені приклади є [помилковими](http://klasnaocinka.com.ua/uk/article/tipovi-pomilki-v-movlenni-ditei-doshkilnogo-viku-2.html), можуть траплятися в суржику.